# Passing Stored Procedure Results into Parameters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters

I am calling a stored procedure (1) within a stored procedure (2). Is there a way to pass values of (1) INTO parameters of (2) so that I can return to the calling program? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can define parameters to be **`INOUT`** or **`OUT`**.

This allows the procedure to pass values back to the caller.

As a brief example, `proc1` has parameters that are defined as INOUT and OUT. In `proc1` values are assigned to those parameters.

And `proc2` calls `proc1`. The values set in `proc1` are available to `proc2`.

```
DELIMITER ;

CREATE PROCEDURE proc1(INOUT ua INT, OUT ob INT)
BEGIN
   SET ua = ua + 1;
   SET ob = 1;
END$$

CREATE PROCEDURE proc2()
BEGIN
   DECLARE a INT;
   DECLARE b INT;
   SET a = 0;
   SET b = 0;
   CALL proc1(a,b);
   SELECT a, b;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL proc2();

   a     b
----  ----
   1     1
```